# HTML5 FileReader API in iPhone5 not getting photo from camera

Tags: image, html, file-io, iphone-5

I'm building a mobile website which lets users upload photos from their camera.

I can get images from the users albums, and I can get images when the user takes a photo in iOS6 on iPhone4 and Android 4, but when the user takes a photo with an iPhone5 (also using iOS6), I get nothing. I can get the image from the users photo albums, but not when taking a photo.

here's the code and jsfiddle below

```
$('input#file_api').change(function(evt){
    var image = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror  = (function(){alert('error reading file')});
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var tempImg = new Image();

          tempImg.src = reader.result;
          tempImg.onload = function(){
             var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                   canvas.width=tempImg.width;
            canvas.height=tempImg.height;
             var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                ctx.drawImage(tempImg,0,0);

               $('body').append(canvas);
})(image);
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
```

I've got an example here http://jsfiddle.net/8DJUy/4/

If you use the file picker to get a photo, it will append the photo to the page. 
If you take a photo with an iPhone5, it won't append anything. But at the same time, it doesn't error out either.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

I can't quite figure out what the problem is with grabbing the photo.

The reason I'm grabbing the photos like this is that the file sizes are quite large when uploaded directly from the phone, and the use case does not require high resolution images, so I'm using the canvas to resize the image before uploading it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
ctx.drawImage(tempImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @furtive, one day I'd like to be one of the smart people who can figure out the details like that. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I had somebody test with the iPhone 5 (I don't have one) and the 'image' they saw was the little icon that shows up in the file selector, not the actual image being read by the above code.